# Sum vector with matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

assume matrix is 2d numpy (MxN) array and vector is 1d array (1xN) - both have same N rows. I need to add to each column in matrix value of same row element in vector:

```
[[1 2 3],
 [4 5 6]]

[0.1 0.2]

result:

[[1.1 2.1 3.1],
 [4.2 5.2 6.2]]
```

Comment: Normally we describe a (M,N) arrays as having `M` rows, `N` columns, though row/column are not formally part of the `numpy` terminology.  A 1d array will have shape (M,), not (1,M).  To do the math you need a (M,1) shape array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `numpy.reshape(-1,1)` and get what you want:

```
l1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5 , 6]])

l2 = np.array([0.1, 0.2]).reshape(-1,1)

l1+l2
```

Output:

```
array([[1.1, 2.1, 3.1],
       [4.2, 5.2, 6.2]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Taking advantage of [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), you can do `a + b[:, None]`:

```
a = np.arange(1,7).reshape((2, 3))
b = np.array([0.1, 0.2])

a + b[:, None]
array([[1.1, 2.1, 3.1],
       [4.2, 5.2, 6.2]])
```

Or:

```
a + b[:, np.newaxis]
array([[1.1, 2.1, 3.1],
       [4.2, 5.2, 6.2]])
```